# Running EMR with Cascading SDK failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, cascading

I was following this tutorial for installing Cascading to EMR:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreateCascading.html

But it failed because of bootstrap action installing the cascading-sdk. The corresponding logs is here: http://pastebin.com/jybHssTQ. As seen from the logs, it's failed because of `apt-get` not found. Seriously?

I also checked the sdk installation script, and found option to disable installing `screen` with --no-screen. It is still failed, with different error http://pastebin.com/T6CvA2H1
And now it is because of permission denied. What?

It's official guide, but I can't seem to run it. Any idea?

Comment: try "yum" instead of "apt-get"

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the script first, try a different EMR AMI version.

AMI versions up until 2.4.8 use Debian OS, where apt-get will work, but this runs Hadoop 1.x. AMI versions 3.0.x run Hadoop 2.2 and use Amazon Linux, which uses Yum.

See Below:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/ami-versions-supported.html

Also, try to add the "--tmpdir" option to get around the "Permission Denied" error.